# Designing a turing Machine belonging to a language

Tags: automata, formal-languages, turing-machines

Im trying to learn the concept of turing machines.I have understood the basic stuff like its a simple mathematical model of a computer and its parts.Now im asked to create a turing machine.

```
Design a turing machine that accept strings belonging to the language
(a + b)* from the alphabet (a, b)
```

Can someone describe to me how it is done?

Comment: What does the "+" denote here?

Comment: @mrp Its a Terminal

Comment: So you want to make a Turing machine that accepts _everything_?

Comment: The plus is NOT a terminal, $(a+b)^*$ is a regular expression meaning that you choose $a$ or $b$ and then take the Kleene star to iterate this. Hence the expression stands for all strings over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Now to construct the Turing machine, what do you know about Turing machines? How would you start constructing one piece by piece (selecting the tape alphabet, machine states, transition function/relation etc.)?